# Распределенные вычисления Java EE

Tags: java, java-ee

Пусть имеем класс-бин. Как реализовать вариант, когда сервер создает очередной экземпляр этого класса, только если такого экземпляра не существует, в противном случае - возвращать ссылку на уже существующий экземпляр класса... Частично данная функциональность реализуется в Session Bean, часть - в Singletone, но можно ли из данной комбинации реализовать то, что нужно, причем в случае кластера эти экземпляры класса могут быть распределены на физически разных машинах (или не могут?).
C уважением, Кудрявцев А.А.

Answer (score 1):

Если ссылка нужна для того, чтобы вызывать методы объекта, то идеально подходит RMI.
Если можно или нужно передать сам объект, который сериализуется, то тут масса способов, начиная с того же RMI и заканчивая CORBA.
Вот список того, что приходит в голову:
RMI, JMS, JMX, Sockets, CORBA.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве мультикластерного кеширование  можно попробывать использовать RMI